# Delta and main indexes in Sphinx. Duplication of search results

Tags: database, search, sphinx

I have two indexes , main and delta. This content have several flags, for example one "published". Main index rebuild once a day , delta - after each edit content . Everything works fine except for one thing . Suppose there is an article , which published = 1. For example, at night main index rebuilded and it remembered that the article published = 1. Then the next day the article is removed from the publication and has published = 0 . If you do a simple search - you can see that the articles published = 0 . But if the filter is set (1) on the field , then the item is published = 1 and it displayed in the search continues. Ie I understand that it was found in the main index. How to make it so that if an item does not meet the needs of searching the delta index, is in the main index Sphinx is not looking for?

I understand that I can delete unpublished data initially using killlist-query, but this method is not suitable because sometimes I need to look for all the articles, and sometimes just published .

Comment: Why Are you using delta index for searching ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The delta index contains data (data not yet in main), thats why you search it!

Answer (score 0):

Use UpdataAttributes API call (or UPDATE ... in sphinxQL) to actully update the published attribute in the main index.